# cast an array into a string - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab

I have an array that I want to basically capture as text so I can write it to one cell of an Excel file as a column header.  It's a range of subjects, and I'll have some data underneath.  So the range is:

```
range = 2:12;
```

which creates and array, but I want the Excel file header to just read 2:12.  I've tried creating another variable to capture this text in one field, using num2str like this:

```
rangeChar = num2str(range);
```

and I get:

```
rangeChar = 2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
```

but they are each separate fields, so when exported to Excel they each take up their own cell.  The original range is not always sequential - for example I might have

```
range = cat(2, 2:4, 8, 9:12);
```

so I can't just do a

```
rangeChar = sprintf('%d:%d', range(1), range(end));
```

type of thing either.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What should the Excel header read when `range = cat(2, 2:4, 8, 9:12)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the other way around and keep the range in the string and extract the vector from that when you need it:

```
rangeChar = '2:12';
range = eval(rangeChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just write :

```
range = '2:12';
```

Comment: I need the range to be an array for other calculations, and when I change it, I don't want to have to use 2 lines (ex. range = 2:12; rangeChar = '2:12';) because if I change one and forget to change the other my output file will be wrong. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Use a cell array to hold "range" and use the following code :

```
range = {2:4, 8, 9:12};
range_str=repmat({''}, size(range));
for i=1:length(range)
    if length(range{i})==1
    range_str{i}=sprintf('%d', range{i});
    else
    range_str{i}=sprintf('%d:%d', range{i}(1), range{i}(end));
    end
end
range_str
```

Output :

```
range_str = 

'2:4'    '8'    '9:12'
```